# Python sqlite3 select rows with only a certain variable value in them on a specific column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a table with following columns

```
command_create_table = """CREATE TABLE if not exists place (
name VARCHAR(100),
lat DOUBLE(100, 10),
lng DOUBLE(100,10),
vicinity VARCHAR(100),
typeOfPlace VARCHAR(100));"""
```

This `typeOfPlace` column can contain types such as `food`, `restaurant`, `museum` etc. Now based on an user input which I capture in a variable called `typeVar` that indicates a specific value in `typeOfPlace` column, I want to retrieve items. So I have below code:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("places.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()      
cursor.execute("SELECT * from place WHERE typeOfPlace=typeVar")
ans= cursor.fetchall()
```

But I am getting error

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from place WHERE typeOfPlace=typeVar")
OperationalError: no such column: typeVar
```

What am I missing? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * from place WHERE typeOfPlace=?", (typeVar,))
```

The trailing comma after typeVar might look odd, but params expects a sequence, and adding the trailing comma makes the value passed a tuple of length 1.

Never use string formatting to pass in values to an SQL query. Bad things can happen if the variable contains SQL syntax. Look up SQL injection attacks for more details on why you should not do this. Passing parameters separately as I’ve done here is the way to go.

Comment: getting error "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"

Comment: @nad I think I had the wrong type of quotation mark, edited if you can try again please.

Comment: getting a different error now "TypeError: execute() takes no keyword arguments" pointing to the same line

Comment: @nad I’ve edited again and think it’s right this time. Third time lucky...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're checking for the literal string `"typeVar"`, not the user input.

Instead of

`cursor.execute("SELECT * from place WHERE typeOfPlace=typeVar")`

try:

`cursor.execute("SELECT * from place WHERE typeOfPlace={}".format(typeVar))`.

Comment: so now if my variable input is "food", it is telling me "no such column as food". Clearly I am not checking for column named food but the rows where "typeOfPlace" column has value "food".

Comment: If you do `select * from place;` what output do you get?

Comment: it outputs the entire table

Comment: And the table has the entries for 'food', etc.?